# Unexplained massive number of shopping Carts in Rails database in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, session, heroku, shopping-cart

I built an e-commerce app using Rails 5, postgres and heroku,  with a classic shopping Cart using the session object to store the cart_id. Thanks to a warning from heroku, I discovered that the numbers of Carts in my database was increasing in a very weird way. It can be more than 50 per minute; and it's not due to many customers visiting the site, which is quite small for the moment. At other moments, the numbers of rows of the Carts table is stable.

Here is my application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  around_action :switch_locale

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  before_action  :current_cart
  after_action :store_action


  def switch_locale(&action)
  locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  I18n.with_locale(locale, &action)
  end

  def default_url_options
    { locale: I18n.locale == I18n.default_locale ? nil : I18n.locale }
  end


  def current_cart

        if session[:cart_id]
          cart = Cart.find_by_id(session[:cart_id])
          if cart == nil
            session[:cart_id] = nil
          end

          if cart.present?
            @current_cart = cart
          else
            session[:cart_id] = nil
          end
        end


        if session[:cart_id] == nil
          @current_cart = Cart.create
          session[:cart_id] = @current_cart.id
        end
  end


  def store_action
      return unless request.get?
      if (request.path != "/users/sign_in" &&
          request.path != "/users/sign_up" &&
          request.path != "/users/password/new" &&
          request.path != "/users/password/edit" &&
          request.path != "/users/confirmation" &&
          request.path != "/users/sign_out" &&
          !request.xhr?) # don't store ajax calls
        store_location_for(:user, request.fullpath)
      end
    end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username])
  end
```

end

cart.rb

```
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :order_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :products, through: :order_items
  monetize :amount_cents_cents
end
```

and the Orders controller:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @order = Order.new

    total = []
    @current_cart.order_items.each do |item|

      total << item.product.price_cents * item.quantity.to_i
    end

    @order.amount_cents_cents = total.sum

    if @order.amount_cents_cents == 0
       Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
       session[:cart_id] = nil
       redirect_to root_path
    else
      @current_cart.order_items.each do |item|
        @order.order_items << item
        item.cart_id = nil
      end

      @user = current_user
      @order.user_id = @user.id
      @order.save


      Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
      session[:cart_id] = nil

      redirect_to order_path(@order)
    end
```

Here are Heroku logs from yesterday :

```
2021-03-09T16:25:31.994631+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:25:31.994568 #4] DEBUG -- : [bc4f12a5-b503-435a-bd45-eac3c3adc006]   Cart Create (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "carts" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2021-03-09 16:25:31.993019"], ["updated_at", "2021-03-09 16:25:31.993019"]]
2021-03-09T16:25:31.996727+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:25:31.996649 #4] DEBUG -- : [bc4f12a5-b503-435a-bd45-eac3c3adc006]    (1.8ms)  COMMIT
2021-03-09T16:25:31.998717+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:25:31.998636 #4] DEBUG -- : [bc4f12a5-b503-435a-bd45-eac3c3adc006]   OrderItem Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "order_items".* FROM "order_items" WHERE "order_items"."cart_id" = $1  [["cart_id", 102580]]
2021-03-09T16:25:31.999401+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:31.999343 #4]  INFO -- : [bc4f12a5-b503-435a-bd45-eac3c3adc006]   Rendering carts/show.html.erb within layouts/application
2021-03-09T16:25:32.000698+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:32.000634 #4]  INFO -- : [bc4f12a5-b503-435a-bd45-eac3c3adc006]   Rendered carts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (1.2ms)
2021-03-09T16:25:32.003572+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:32.003492 #4]  INFO -- : [bc4f12a5-b503-435a-bd45-eac3c3adc006]   Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (2.0ms)
2021-03-09T16:25:32.003861+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:32.003787 #4]  INFO -- : [bc4f12a5-b503-435a-bd45-eac3c3adc006]   Rendered shared/_flashes.html.erb (0.1ms)
2021-03-09T16:25:32.004305+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:32.004209 #4]  INFO -- : [bc4f12a5-b503-435a-bd45-eac3c3adc006] Completed 200 OK in 14ms (Views: 5.0ms | ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)
2021-03-09T16:25:32.006089+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/en/carts/100155" host=www.bravacoffeeroasters.com request_id=bc4f12a5-b503-435a-bd45-eac3c3adc006 fwd="5.9.108.254" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=20ms status=200 bytes=8003 protocol=https
2021-03-09T16:25:39.827045+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:39.826944 #4]  INFO -- : [794133c6-3a8d-4952-b38b-148dd1c78941] Started GET "/en/carts/100158" for 5.9.108.254 at 2021-03-09 16:25:39 +0000
2021-03-09T16:25:39.828020+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:39.827942 #4]  INFO -- : [794133c6-3a8d-4952-b38b-148dd1c78941] Processing by CartsController#show as HTML
2021-03-09T16:25:39.828070+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:39.828014 #4]  INFO -- : [794133c6-3a8d-4952-b38b-148dd1c78941]   Parameters: {"locale"=>"en", "id"=>"100158"}
2021-03-09T16:25:39.831671+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:25:39.831585 #4] DEBUG -- : [794133c6-3a8d-4952-b38b-148dd1c78941]    (1.2ms)  BEGIN
2021-03-09T16:25:39.834022+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:25:39.833931 #4] DEBUG -- : [794133c6-3a8d-4952-b38b-148dd1c78941]   Cart Create (1.3ms)  INSERT INTO "carts" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2021-03-09 16:25:39.832057"], ["updated_at", "2021-03-09 16:25:39.832057"]]
2021-03-09T16:25:39.836952+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:25:39.836843 #4] DEBUG -- : [794133c6-3a8d-4952-b38b-148dd1c78941]    (2.6ms)  COMMIT
2021-03-09T16:25:39.838769+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:25:39.838664 #4] DEBUG -- : [794133c6-3a8d-4952-b38b-148dd1c78941]   OrderItem Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "order_items".* FROM "order_items" WHERE "order_items"."cart_id" = $1  [["cart_id", 102581]]
2021-03-09T16:25:39.839411+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:39.839342 #4]  INFO -- : [794133c6-3a8d-4952-b38b-148dd1c78941]   Rendering carts/show.html.erb within layouts/application
2021-03-09T16:25:39.840887+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:39.840812 #4]  INFO -- : [794133c6-3a8d-4952-b38b-148dd1c78941]   Rendered carts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (1.4ms)
2021-03-09T16:25:39.843830+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:39.843767 #4]  INFO -- : [794133c6-3a8d-4952-b38b-148dd1c78941]   Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (2.0ms)
2021-03-09T16:25:39.844041+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:39.843979 #4]  INFO -- : [794133c6-3a8d-4952-b38b-148dd1c78941]   Rendered shared/_flashes.html.erb (0.1ms)
2021-03-09T16:25:39.844419+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:39.844315 #4]  INFO -- : [794133c6-3a8d-4952-b38b-148dd1c78941] Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 5.1ms | ActiveRecord: 6.2ms)
2021-03-09T16:25:39.846119+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/en/carts/100158" host=www.bravacoffeeroasters.com request_id=794133c6-3a8d-4952-b38b-148dd1c78941 fwd="5.9.108.254" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=21ms status=200 bytes=8007 protocol=https
2021-03-09T16:25:44.393247+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:44.393143 #4]  INFO -- : [55da48a9-0088-4a3d-984a-f58f8a81245a] Started GET "/en/carts/100162" for 5.9.108.254 at 2021-03-09 16:25:44 +0000
2021-03-09T16:25:44.394349+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:44.394257 #4]  INFO -- : [55da48a9-0088-4a3d-984a-f58f8a81245a] Processing by CartsController#show as HTML
2021-03-09T16:25:44.394397+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:44.394331 #4]  INFO -- : [55da48a9-0088-4a3d-984a-f58f8a81245a]   Parameters: {"locale"=>"en", "id"=>"100162"}
2021-03-09T16:25:44.402068+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:25:44.401988 #4] DEBUG -- : [55da48a9-0088-4a3d-984a-f58f8a81245a]    (1.0ms)  BEGIN
2021-03-09T16:25:44.404434+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:25:44.404308 #4] DEBUG -- : [55da48a9-0088-4a3d-984a-f58f8a81245a]   Cart Create (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "carts" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2021-03-09 16:25:44.402575"], ["updated_at", "2021-03-09 16:25:44.402575"]]
2021-03-09T16:25:44.406742+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:25:44.406662 #4] DEBUG -- : [55da48a9-0088-4a3d-984a-f58f8a81245a]    (1.9ms)  COMMIT
2021-03-09T16:25:44.408565+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:25:44.408479 #4] DEBUG -- : [55da48a9-0088-4a3d-984a-f58f8a81245a]   OrderItem Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "order_items".* FROM "order_items" WHERE "order_items"."cart_id" = $1  [["cart_id", 102582]]
2021-03-09T16:25:44.409183+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:44.409106 #4]  INFO -- : [55da48a9-0088-4a3d-984a-f58f8a81245a]   Rendering carts/show.html.erb within layouts/application
2021-03-09T16:25:44.410524+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:44.410452 #4]  INFO -- : [55da48a9-0088-4a3d-984a-f58f8a81245a]   Rendered carts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (1.2ms)
2021-03-09T16:25:44.413558+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:44.413470 #4]  INFO -- : [55da48a9-0088-4a3d-984a-f58f8a81245a]   Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (2.0ms)
2021-03-09T16:25:44.413840+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:44.413772 #4]  INFO -- : [55da48a9-0088-4a3d-984a-f58f8a81245a]   Rendered shared/_flashes.html.erb (0.1ms)
2021-03-09T16:25:44.414160+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:44.414098 #4]  INFO -- : [55da48a9-0088-4a3d-984a-f58f8a81245a] Completed 200 OK in 20ms (Views: 5.1ms | ActiveRecord: 5.2ms)
2021-03-09T16:25:44.416182+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/en/carts/100162" host=www.bravacoffeeroasters.com request_id=55da48a9-0088-4a3d-984a-f58f8a81245a fwd="5.9.108.254" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=25ms status=200 bytes=8001 protocol=https
2021-03-09T16:25:49.749861+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:49.749718 #4]  INFO -- : [c9f138de-a820-4b0b-b87e-ad2f99f6c9f5] Started GET "/en/carts/100167" for 5.9.108.254 at 2021-03-09 16:25:49 +0000
2021-03-09T16:25:49.751269+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:49.751173 #4]  INFO -- : [c9f138de-a820-4b0b-b87e-ad2f99f6c9f5] Processing by CartsController#show as HTML
2021-03-09T16:25:49.751359+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:49.751277 #4]  INFO -- : [c9f138de-a820-4b0b-b87e-ad2f99f6c9f5]   Parameters: {"locale"=>"en", "id"=>"100167"}
2021-03-09T16:25:49.754570+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:25:49.754464 #4] DEBUG -- : [c9f138de-a820-4b0b-b87e-ad2f99f6c9f5]    (1.1ms)  BEGIN
2021-03-09T16:25:49.757801+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:25:49.757693 #4] DEBUG -- : [c9f138de-a820-4b0b-b87e-ad2f99f6c9f5]   Cart Create (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "carts" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2021-03-09 16:25:49.755581"], ["updated_at", "2021-03-09 16:25:49.755581"]]
2021-03-09T16:25:49.760623+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:25:49.760418 #4] DEBUG -- : [c9f138de-a820-4b0b-b87e-ad2f99f6c9f5]    (2.2ms)  COMMIT
2021-03-09T16:25:49.762818+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:25:49.762617 #4] DEBUG -- : [c9f138de-a820-4b0b-b87e-ad2f99f6c9f5]   OrderItem Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "order_items".* FROM "order_items" WHERE "order_items"."cart_id" = $1  [["cart_id", 102583]]
2021-03-09T16:25:49.764416+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:49.764303 #4]  INFO -- : [c9f138de-a820-4b0b-b87e-ad2f99f6c9f5]   Rendering carts/show.html.erb within layouts/application
2021-03-09T16:25:49.766505+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:49.766423 #4]  INFO -- : [c9f138de-a820-4b0b-b87e-ad2f99f6c9f5]   Rendered carts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (1.9ms)
2021-03-09T16:25:49.771851+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:49.771765 #4]  INFO -- : [c9f138de-a820-4b0b-b87e-ad2f99f6c9f5]   Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (3.8ms)
2021-03-09T16:25:49.772151+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:49.772072 #4]  INFO -- : [c9f138de-a820-4b0b-b87e-ad2f99f6c9f5]   Rendered shared/_flashes.html.erb (0.1ms)
2021-03-09T16:25:49.772669+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:49.772589 #4]  INFO -- : [c9f138de-a820-4b0b-b87e-ad2f99f6c9f5] Completed 200 OK in 21ms (Views: 8.7ms | ActiveRecord: 5.7ms)
2021-03-09T16:25:49.775098+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/en/carts/100167" host=www.bravacoffeeroasters.com request_id=c9f138de-a820-4b0b-b87e-ad2f99f6c9f5 fwd="5.9.108.254" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=28ms status=200 bytes=8005 protocol=https
2021-03-09T16:25:55.885797+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:55.885705 #4]  INFO -- : [e2305a65-52be-432a-867f-ac1c0f459e1b] Started GET "/en/carts/100171" for 5.9.108.254 at 2021-03-09 16:25:55 +0000
2021-03-09T16:25:55.886791+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:55.886726 #4]  INFO -- : [e2305a65-52be-432a-867f-ac1c0f459e1b] Processing by CartsController#show as HTML
2021-03-09T16:25:55.886851+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:55.886800 #4]  INFO -- : [e2305a65-52be-432a-867f-ac1c0f459e1b]   Parameters: {"locale"=>"en", "id"=>"100171"}
2021-03-09T16:25:55.889588+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:25:55.889521 #4] DEBUG -- : [e2305a65-52be-432a-867f-ac1c0f459e1b]    (1.0ms)  BEGIN
2021-03-09T16:25:55.891685+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:25:55.891611 #4] DEBUG -- : [e2305a65-52be-432a-867f-ac1c0f459e1b]   Cart Create (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "carts" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2021-03-09 16:25:55.889991"], ["updated_at", "2021-03-09 16:25:55.889991"]]
2021-03-09T16:25:55.894147+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:25:55.894080 #4] DEBUG -- : [e2305a65-52be-432a-867f-ac1c0f459e1b]    (2.1ms)  COMMIT
2021-03-09T16:25:55.895883+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:25:55.895820 #4] DEBUG -- : [e2305a65-52be-432a-867f-ac1c0f459e1b]   OrderItem Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "order_items".* FROM "order_items" WHERE "order_items"."cart_id" = $1  [["cart_id", 102584]]
2021-03-09T16:25:55.896595+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:55.896512 #4]  INFO -- : [e2305a65-52be-432a-867f-ac1c0f459e1b]   Rendering carts/show.html.erb within layouts/application
2021-03-09T16:25:55.898042+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:55.897982 #4]  INFO -- : [e2305a65-52be-432a-867f-ac1c0f459e1b]   Rendered carts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (1.4ms)
2021-03-09T16:25:55.900969+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:55.900906 #4]  INFO -- : [e2305a65-52be-432a-867f-ac1c0f459e1b]   Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (2.0ms)
2021-03-09T16:25:55.901154+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:55.901098 #4]  INFO -- : [e2305a65-52be-432a-867f-ac1c0f459e1b]   Rendered shared/_flashes.html.erb (0.0ms)
2021-03-09T16:25:55.901439+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:25:55.901385 #4]  INFO -- : [e2305a65-52be-432a-867f-ac1c0f459e1b] Completed 200 OK in 14ms (Views: 5.1ms | ActiveRecord: 5.3ms)
2021-03-09T16:25:55.903393+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/en/carts/100171" host=www.bravacoffeeroasters.com request_id=e2305a65-52be-432a-867f-ac1c0f459e1b fwd="5.9.108.254" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=20ms status=200 bytes=8005 protocol=https
2021-03-09T16:26:02.095206+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:26:02.095107 #4]  INFO -- : [59ebb736-4614-4052-97dd-9517cfd2af70] Started GET "/en/carts/100176" for 5.9.108.254 at 2021-03-09 16:26:02 +0000
2021-03-09T16:26:02.096223+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:26:02.096121 #4]  INFO -- : [59ebb736-4614-4052-97dd-9517cfd2af70] Processing by CartsController#show as HTML
2021-03-09T16:26:02.096287+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:26:02.096209 #4]  INFO -- : [59ebb736-4614-4052-97dd-9517cfd2af70]   Parameters: {"locale"=>"en", "id"=>"100176"}
2021-03-09T16:26:02.099292+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:26:02.099195 #4] DEBUG -- : [59ebb736-4614-4052-97dd-9517cfd2af70]    (1.0ms)  BEGIN
2021-03-09T16:26:02.101864+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:26:02.101787 #4] DEBUG -- : [59ebb736-4614-4052-97dd-9517cfd2af70]   Cart Create (1.3ms)  INSERT INTO "carts" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2021-03-09 16:26:02.099815"], ["updated_at", "2021-03-09 16:26:02.099815"]]
2021-03-09T16:26:02.104590+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:26:02.104462 #4] DEBUG -- : [59ebb736-4614-4052-97dd-9517cfd2af70]    (2.3ms)  COMMIT
2021-03-09T16:26:02.106692+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:26:02.106619 #4] DEBUG -- : [59ebb736-4614-4052-97dd-9517cfd2af70]   OrderItem Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "order_items".* FROM "order_items" WHERE "order_items"."cart_id" = $1  [["cart_id", 102585]]
2021-03-09T16:26:02.107212+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:26:02.107150 #4]  INFO -- : [59ebb736-4614-4052-97dd-9517cfd2af70]   Rendering carts/show.html.erb within layouts/application
2021-03-09T16:26:02.108495+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:26:02.108422 #4]  INFO -- : [59ebb736-4614-4052-97dd-9517cfd2af70]   Rendered carts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (1.2ms)
2021-03-09T16:26:02.111100+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:26:02.111034 #4]  INFO -- : [59ebb736-4614-4052-97dd-9517cfd2af70]   Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (1.7ms)
2021-03-09T16:26:02.111294+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:26:02.111230 #4]  INFO -- : [59ebb736-4614-4052-97dd-9517cfd2af70]   Rendered shared/_flashes.html.erb (0.1ms)
2021-03-09T16:26:02.111695+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:26:02.111563 #4]  INFO -- : [59ebb736-4614-4052-97dd-9517cfd2af70] Completed 200 OK in 15ms (Views: 4.5ms | ActiveRecord: 5.9ms)
2021-03-09T16:26:02.114053+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/en/carts/100176" host=www.bravacoffeeroasters.com request_id=59ebb736-4614-4052-97dd-9517cfd2af70 fwd="5.9.108.254" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=21ms status=200 bytes=8011 protocol=https
2021-03-09T16:26:07.168587+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:26:07.168395 #4]  INFO -- : [512ac9cd-da40-435d-a7b8-986ad4209a31] Started GET "/en/carts/100181" for 5.9.108.254 at 2021-03-09 16:26:07 +0000
2021-03-09T16:26:07.169524+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:26:07.169461 #4]  INFO -- : [512ac9cd-da40-435d-a7b8-986ad4209a31] Processing by CartsController#show as HTML
2021-03-09T16:26:07.169585+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:26:07.169533 #4]  INFO -- : [512ac9cd-da40-435d-a7b8-986ad4209a31]   Parameters: {"locale"=>"en", "id"=>"100181"}
2021-03-09T16:26:07.172559+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:26:07.172490 #4] DEBUG -- : [512ac9cd-da40-435d-a7b8-986ad4209a31]    (1.0ms)  BEGIN
2021-03-09T16:26:07.174639+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:26:07.174577 #4] DEBUG -- : [512ac9cd-da40-435d-a7b8-986ad4209a31]   Cart Create (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "carts" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2021-03-09 16:26:07.172954"], ["updated_at", "2021-03-09 16:26:07.172954"]]
2021-03-09T16:26:07.176801+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:26:07.176731 #4] DEBUG -- : [512ac9cd-da40-435d-a7b8-986ad4209a31]    (1.9ms)  COMMIT
2021-03-09T16:26:07.178631+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:26:07.178567 #4] DEBUG -- : [512ac9cd-da40-435d-a7b8-986ad4209a31]   OrderItem Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "order_items".* FROM "order_items" WHERE "order_items"."cart_id" = $1  [["cart_id", 102586]]
2021-03-09T16:26:07.179179+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:26:07.179119 #4]  INFO -- : [512ac9cd-da40-435d-a7b8-986ad4209a31]   Rendering carts/show.html.erb within layouts/application
2021-03-09T16:26:07.180626+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:26:07.180554 #4]  INFO -- : [512ac9cd-da40-435d-a7b8-986ad4209a31]   Rendered carts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (1.3ms)
2021-03-09T16:26:07.183396+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:26:07.183332 #4]  INFO -- : [512ac9cd-da40-435d-a7b8-986ad4209a31]   Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (1.9ms)
2021-03-09T16:26:07.183592+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:26:07.183524 #4]  INFO -- : [512ac9cd-da40-435d-a7b8-986ad4209a31]   Rendered shared/_flashes.html.erb (0.0ms)
2021-03-09T16:26:07.183924+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:26:07.183852 #4]  INFO -- : [512ac9cd-da40-435d-a7b8-986ad4209a31] Completed 200 OK in 14ms (Views: 4.8ms | ActiveRecord: 5.1ms)
2021-03-09T16:26:07.186556+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/en/carts/100181" host=www.bravacoffeeroasters.com request_id=512ac9cd-da40-435d-a7b8-986ad4209a31 fwd="5.9.108.254" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=20ms status=200 bytes=8009 protocol=https
2021-03-09T16:26:12.791059+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:26:12.790956 #4]  INFO -- : [ee78de9f-ffb9-4c3b-a484-8438903fd9c9] Started GET "/en/carts/100185" for 5.9.108.254 at 2021-03-09 16:26:12 +0000
2021-03-09T16:26:12.792005+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:26:12.791938 #4]  INFO -- : [ee78de9f-ffb9-4c3b-a484-8438903fd9c9] Processing by CartsController#show as HTML
2021-03-09T16:26:12.792075+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:26:12.792011 #4]  INFO -- : [ee78de9f-ffb9-4c3b-a484-8438903fd9c9]   Parameters: {"locale"=>"en", "id"=>"100185"}
2021-03-09T16:26:12.794860+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:26:12.794781 #4] DEBUG -- : [ee78de9f-ffb9-4c3b-a484-8438903fd9c9]    (1.0ms)  BEGIN
2021-03-09T16:26:12.797433+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:26:12.797358 #4] DEBUG -- : [ee78de9f-ffb9-4c3b-a484-8438903fd9c9]   Cart Create (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "carts" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2021-03-09 16:26:12.795289"], ["updated_at", "2021-03-09 16:26:12.795289"]]
2021-03-09T16:26:12.799742+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:26:12.799657 #4] DEBUG -- : [ee78de9f-ffb9-4c3b-a484-8438903fd9c9]    (1.8ms)  COMMIT
2021-03-09T16:26:12.801691+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2021-03-09T16:26:12.801618 #4] DEBUG -- : [ee78de9f-ffb9-4c3b-a484-8438903fd9c9]   OrderItem Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "order_items".* FROM "order_items" WHERE "order_items"."cart_id" = $1  [["cart_id", 102587]]
2021-03-09T16:26:12.802222+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:26:12.802153 #4]  INFO -- : [ee78de9f-ffb9-4c3b-a484-8438903fd9c9]   Rendering carts/show.html.erb within layouts/application
2021-03-09T16:26:12.803798+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:26:12.803727 #4]  INFO -- : [ee78de9f-ffb9-4c3b-a484-8438903fd9c9]   Rendered carts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (1.5ms)
2021-03-09T16:26:12.807236+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:26:12.807070 #4]  INFO -- : [ee78de9f-ffb9-4c3b-a484-8438903fd9c9]   Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (2.3ms)
2021-03-09T16:26:12.807516+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:26:12.807446 #4]  INFO -- : [ee78de9f-ffb9-4c3b-a484-8438903fd9c9]   Rendered shared/_flashes.html.erb (0.1ms)
2021-03-09T16:26:12.807908+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-03-09T16:26:12.807840 #4]  INFO -- : [ee78de9f-ffb9-4c3b-a484-8438903fd9c9] Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 5.8ms | ActiveRecord: 5.2ms)
2021-03-09T16:26:12.809202+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/en/carts/100185" host=www.bravacoffeeroasters.com request_id=ee78de9f-ffb9-4c3b-a484-8438903fd9c9 fwd="5.9.108.254" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=20ms status=200 bytes=8013 protocol=https
```

I deleted all the Carts of the production database yesterday and today I have already more than 3000 rows. This sounds bad to me. Is anyone could help fixing the problem?

Comment: I don't think this can be figured out through static code analysis. Perhaps you should add some debug logging.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @LaurenzAlbe, I edited the issue with Heroku logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am reading your code correctly:

```
before_action  :current_cart
def current_cart
  ...
  if session[:cart_id] == nil
    @current_cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = @current_cart.id
  end
end
```

A [before_action](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods/before_action) added in `ApplicationController` will execute for every action in every controller that inherits from `ApplicationController`.

Even your homepage probably executes it. When `session[:cart_id]` is nil (which by your current issue, it happens a lot) every access will create a `Cart`.

The purpose of `current_cart`, IMO, same as `current_user` is to find a cart not create one. If it's not present, then it's other action's purpose to create it.

You should revise your logic a little. Good luck!

Comment: I think you're right here, `GET "/en/carts/:id"` probably shouldn't be creating a cart.

Comment: Thanks @razvans and mu is too short ! I modified my code in order to create a cart only when needed. It's not perfect yet but the Cart.count is 0 in the Heroku console for one hour now so it's a relief! Yet, do you think it would still be useful to use rack-attack as if the site was a target once, it could be the target of other dangerous spiders or bots?

Comment: Well if you had rack-attack you probably wouldn't have caught this issue. I say you make sure all endpoints are safe, optimised and fast then bots harmless.